# Canada eTA or Visa?

Tags: visas, canada, filipino-citizens, cruising, eta

I am a Filipino citizen with a valid US visa and a Canada eTA. I will fly to Canada as a tourist for a few days. Then from Canada, I will fly to Seattle, USA to join an Alaska Cruise. Disembarkation is also in Seattle, USA. One of the ports in the cruise is Victoria, BC Canada, arrives at 8 pm and departs at 11:59 pm, bound for Seattle, USA. Will my Canada eTA still be valid in the port of Victoria? Or do I need a Canada visa?

After the cruise, I will fly back to Canada for a few days before heading back home.

Comment: What kind of US visa do you have? Are you a lawful permanent resident of the US? Because Filipino nationals usually need a visa for Canada. How did you get the eTA?

Comment: I am a Filipino citizen. Canada recently exempted Filipinos on the visa requirement on certain conditions. I met those conditions so was given an eTA valid for 5 years

Comment: I am not a US permanent resident. What I have is a US tourist visa and a Canada eTA

Comment: @DJClayworth Canada recently (last month I think) changed the rules to allow Filipinos with US non-immigrant visas to use eTA instead of needing a visa

Comment: Unfortunately, per the answer below, this only applies to flights and visa still needed for cruise ship arrivals

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, it looks like you'll need a regular visitor's visa for the cruise ship stop. eTA's are multi-entry, but only for arrival by air.

From Canada.ca page on [electronic travel authorization](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/eligibility.html): who can apply:

> You may be eligible to apply for an eTA (instead of a visitor visa) if
> you’re a:
>
> - Citizen from select visa-required countries and you’re travelling to
>   Canada by air.
> - **However, you still need visitor visa (not an eTA) when
>   arriving by car, bus, train, or boat, including a cruise ship.**

You should check with the cruise line, but they normally won't allow you to board without a valid visa, even if you don't plan to disembark in Canadian territory.